# Zlib decompress script working on linux but not on windows: error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, zlib

I've done a script on python 2.7 for decompress a file using zlib.
I've used it on Linux and it is working, but when I try to run it on windows i get the following error:

> Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream.

I'm using this code:

`datosComprimidos = open(archivo).read()
 datosDescomprimidos = zlib.decompress(datosComprimidos)`

Also, I've try this other code:

```
datosDescomprimidos = zlib.decompressobj().decompress(datosComprimidos, zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

But in this case, it writes nothing on datosDescomprimidos.

Any one know something about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, because

```
datosComprimidos = open(archivo).read()
```

returns the data open in *text* mode. You need to read it in binary mode:

```
datosComprimidos = open(archivo,"rb").read()
```

it doesn't matter on Linux, but it does matter in Windows, because else, all `10` values are prepended with `13` values and it corrupts the data (adding CR before LF to be windows text compliant doesn't apply for a binary stream!)

As a bonus, your code is now python 3 compliant.

Note that it would be more pythonic to use that in a `with` block:

```
with open(archivo,"rb") as f:
   datosComprimidos = f.read()
```

so we control when the file is closed (when exiting the block)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem!

Comment: when I get downvotes, I like to have some explanation about it... I really don't care, as you can see I can take some, but there, I'm puzzled.

Comment: thank you for this information. It's not the official way to contact the team but NVM. I'll pass this on to the other mods/SE employees.